# Plotting a function in python matplotlib

Tags: python, matlab, function, plot

Here is my code:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import agent




deer = agent.Agent()
print(deer.x,deer.y)
deer.step()

print(deer.x,deer.y)

def walk(length):


    for i in range(length):
        #while deer.x <= i:
        deer.step()
        countx= deer.x + 1
        county=deer.y +1

        #print(countx,county)
        x= countx
        y= county
    return deer.step()

walk(100)

walker = walk(100)
plt.plot(walk[0],walk[1],label= 'Random walk')
plt.scatter(walk[0],walk[1],s=50,c=range(101))
plt.show()
```

I'm trying to get the count step of x and y to be graphed.But I don't understand why it wont recognize the x and y values within the function. The goal is to plot the 100 random steps taken.

After there is a plot from the 100 steps taken, I'm trying to create a second Method for taking a step. Instead of choosing a random new angle and moving, the current orientation of the agent should change by a random amount chosen from a normal distribution with mean 0 and standard deviation Sigma=1 (self.orientation = self.orientation + np.random.normal(0,Sigma)).

It's also suppose to walk 100 steps, and show the trajectory using matplolib, and show the distance between the agent and it's starting point.

I used the class Agent:

```
    class Agent:
# initializer with default argument value
def __init__(self,sigma=0.5):
    self.x = 0.0 # agent's x position
    self.y = 0.0 # agent's y position
    self.o = 0.0 # agent's orientation
    self.v = 1.0 # agent's velocity
    self.sigma = sigma

def step(self):
    self.o = random.random()*2*np.pi
    self.x +=self.v*np.cos(self.o)
    self.y += self.v*np.sin(self.o)

def turn(self):
    self.o += np.random.normal(0,self.sigma)
    self.x += self.v*np.cos(self.o)
    self.y += self.v*np.sin(self.o)

def distance(self):
    return np.sqrt(self.x**2 + self.y**2)
```

Comment: Is the code you put with your question working? Firstly some modules are not imported, but more importantly, as far as I can see `walk` is a function that does not return a value - yet you reference it as an array i.e. for your plots `walk[0]` etc. Am I missing something?

Comment: I just don't know how to plot the function walk, the code itself works though. I'm just stuck